# Остановка работы слайдера immersive slider по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Слайдер работает на JQuery. Для активации работы слайдера задаются начальные значения. Далее я пытаюсь изменить значения autoStart по клику, но выдается ошибка, что нет такой функции.

```
$("#immersive_slider").immersive_slider({
          animation: "fade", // As usual, you can change the animation to these: slide (default), bounce, fade, slideUp, and bounceUp
          slideSelector: ".slide", // This option will let you assign custom selector for each slides in case .slide is already taken
          container: ".main", // This option lets you define the container of which the background will appear. Make sure the slider is inside this container as well.
          cssBlur: false, // Experimental: In case you don't want to keep adding new data-blurred attributes, trigger this to true and it will generate the blur image on the fly (more info below).
          pagination: false, // Toggle this to false if you don't want a pagination
          loop: true, // Toggle to false if you don't want the slider to loop. Default is true.
          autoStart: 15000 // Define the number of milliseconds before it navigates automatically. Change this to 0 or false to disable autoStart. The default value is 5000.
        });
     
$('#is-pause').click( ()=>{
          
          $("#immersive_slider").immersive_slider({
            autoStart: 999999 
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У него нет таких методов. только эти: `movePrev()`, `moveNext()`  [исходники с описанием тут](https://github.com/peachananr/immersive-slider) (https://github.com/peachananr/immersive-slider)

Вот в этих строчках все и крутится:

```
if(settings.autoStart != 0 || settings.autoStart != false) {
  setInterval(function() {
    el.moveNext();
  }, settings.autoStart);
}
```

Нужно сделать доступ извне к  `settings.autoStart`

Лицензии нет - можно поставить [⭐️](https://github.com/peachananr/immersive-slider/stargazers) автору и сделать пулреквест с новым функционалом.